# Cocos-Code-IDE- How to call java method in cocos2dx using lua language

Tags: java, android, lua

I'm using Cocos-Code-IDE to create my game with lua language. Now I want to call some java method in Activity class.

For example: call method showAds() in Activity class when click to button on game scene.

I've searched but don't have any...

Please help me...

Comment: Pleas add more details to your code

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing called Java Native Interface (JNI). It allows one to call java methods from C++. 
So the first thing you have to do is to create a C++ code.

1. You need to create a new directory in cocos/. Let it be MyJavaCall.
2. Inside MyJavaCall you create MyJavaCall.cpp and MyJavaCall.hpp.
3. Then you should probably read this tutorial http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/User_Tutorial-Call_Java_functions_in_Cocos2d-x
4. Later this tutorial http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Binding_Custom_Class_To_Lua_Runtime for binding your C++ library to Lua.

Not sure if the tutorials are relevant with the latest cocos2d version. But at least they'll give you an idea. I hope you'll find this answer useful.